# When querying for a hotel/flight/cruise price, how is the currency code processed?

Tags: sabre

I'm very interested in presenting **Sabre** as a solution to my boss.

However, I couldn't ascertain from the public documentation just how the currency code parameters affect the returned price, ie. is it converted, is it the local/'native' price, and then what happens if the queried product is available but not in the specified currency?

Answer (score 0):

in the hotels api (CSL) the availability response will have a node called ConvertedRateInfo which will have the currency you specified in the request